# Why can't I change the vector inside of an instantiated object?

Tags: c++, oop, exception

I have a list of objects and I'm trying to remove the first element of a vector in each of those objects. The way I've been trying to do it keeps throwing an exception.

I tried using get functions but that isn't working? Is that because the get function is maybe returning a copy instead of the actual thing?

```
void Interpreter::createQueryList()
{
    queryList = datalogProgram.getQueries();

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < queryList.size(); ++i)
    {
        queryList.at(i).getParamList().erase( queryList.at(i).getParamList().begin());
        queryList.at(i).getBoolList().erase( queryList.at(i).getBoolList().begin());
    }

}
```

Comment: We have no way of knowing any of that. Present a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `getParamList()` returns a copy, as you say, then `getParamList().erase` returns a copy, and so does `getParamList().begin()`. But the `begin()` is an iterator in the second copy, not the first copy. Erasing an iterator from a different container is Undefined Behavior, which is much worse than just removing an element from a temporary copy.